Edit a number for each line of a file
I can't find what I want :
A file with
102030 name address otherthings
103040 name2 address2 otherthings
104050 name3 address3 otherthings

I just want to do a -1000 for each line but only for the first "field".
Do you have any quick command to edit the file with a bath?

awk '$1-=1000'?

Please show your attempt at solving this

Command below will subtract 1000 from the first field of each line. It will also write the modified lines to a new file called output.txt. Test it with new file first to see it is working or not.
awk '{ $1 = $1 - 1000; print }' file.txt > output.txt

If it is worked then use this to modify original file
awk '{ $1 = $1 - 1000; print }' file.txt > temp.txt && mv temp.txt file.txt

